# Transfer NFT - cannot determine tokenID

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft

How do I transfer an **NFT **(**Zed.Run**) from my smart contract?
I can't seem to determine the *tokenID* or contract address from the NFT and it seems necessary to use the transferFrom or safeTransferFrom methods.

I'm able to receive and send funds via my smart contract (polygon, Avax & Klaytn), however, transferring an NFT seems to require a tokenID (which I cannot determine from any commands).

Comment: Can you please share with us the smart contract address and network you are using? And also elaborate more on the overall flow. You have a smart contract that owns an NFT and now you want to transfer?

Comment: The contract address on Polygon is 0x3Dd8f7eaE6b15eD8C206E67233A7248C009D18a6

The overall flow is to have the capacity to identify an incoming NFT from the contract.  I can identify incoming tx's easily using msg.sender & msg.value.  There does not seem to be identifiers for NFT's.

Comment: So to sum up what I understood until now, you have a smart contract that is the owner of some NFT and you want to transfer it?
Also can you please update your question and include the contract's code?

Comment: The smart contract can currently identify incoming transactions, just not NFT's.

Answer (score 1):

**To make sure we are on the same page:**

1. By saying NFT I'm assuming you mean the ERC721 protocol.
2. You are the owner of a smart contract that owns an NFT.
3. You want to transfer that NFT to another wallet/smart contract.

**To transfer an NFT from an existing smart contract these are the steps:**

1. Identify the NFT id you want to transfer. You can use the [block explorer](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x3Dd8f7eaE6b15eD8C206E67233A7248C009D18a6#nfttransfers) for that. The link I've provided is your smart contract, so you can check which NFTs that smart contract owns.
2. Add a new function on your smart contract to transfer NFT(ERC721), Something like this

```
    function transferERC721(
        address tokenAddress,
        address target,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external{
        IERC721(tokenAddress).safeTransferFrom(address(this), target, tokenId);
    }
```

And then initiate that transaction with data of the NFT(token address & id) you want to transfer.

**A few important notes:**

- Your smart contract can't detect the incoming NFTs because there is
  no such built-in functionality.
- You should add access control, to make sure only **you** can transfer that NFT. [Examples by OpenZepplin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control)
- In case your smart contract doesn't have this kind of function already implemented, then the NFT is stuck. Because smart contracts are immutable and you can't update their code after deploying. Unless you defined the smart contract to be upgradeable ([source](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable)) before deploying it.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  Is there anyway to identify (using Solidity) the tokenID of the smart contracts that have been sent to my contract?